# Failure installing and running couchdb on Lubuntu

Tags: troubleshooting, couchdb

I'm trying to get started using CouchDB on a laptop where I recently installed Lubuntu (15.10). I'm having strange issues..

Yesterday, I installed CouchDB (sudo apt-get install couchdb) and it ran fine.

Today when I turned the computer back on, I noticed I could not load any Futon page from CouchDB - it wasn't running.

My problems are mostly similar to those described here:
[Installation problems with CouchDB 1.6 on Ubuntu 15.10](https://serverfault.com/questions/734611/installation-problems-with-couchdb-1-6-on-ubuntu-15-10)
However, trying to fix this I also attempted to re-install CouchDB with apt-get. (Issued remove command, removed /etc/couchdb, did apt-get install). This install now fails with

```
chmod: cannot access ‘/etc/couchdb/local.ini’: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package couchdb (--configure):
 underprosessen installerte post-installation-skript returnerte feilstatus 1
Det oppstod feil ved behandlinga av:
 couchdb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and this error keeps appearing again whenever I'm installing something. How can I fix these issues (or at least figure out what the problems really are)?

Comment: Also, the solution given in that other post does not help here - trying to (re)start with the /etc/init.d/couchdb script outputs nothing and it's not actually running. Once it ran briefly long enough to let me load the default status message from the server's URL in a browser, but on reload it had shut down again.

Comment: This could be a mistake in the package.  What happens if you --purge and then reinstall?

Answer (score 0):

That specific installation error did go away by creating the local.ini file it wanted. I don't understand how it get into that state in the first place, but

```
sudo touch /etc/couchdb/local.ini
sudo chown couchdb:couchdb /etc/couchdb/local.ini
sudo apt-get install couchdb
```

did the trick and the installation process completed.